# Hide asmx web methods conditionally in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, conditional-statements, asmx, webmethod

How can I conditionally hide the web methods? I don't want to expose the web method if a flag setup in web.config is false. If it is true, then I will expose the web method.

Meaning: The method should only be visible to the client if the flag is true otherwise it should not be available for the client.

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "expose"?

Comment: I mean, the method should only be visible to the client if the web configuration value is true otherwise it should not be available to the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the flag in your method and throw an exception if it's not set.

Comment: I don't want to allow the client to see this method at all if the flag is false.

Comment: That won't be simple.  You can try overriding the listing system; good luck.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I have to leave the methods as is then :(

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do this.

Your clients "see" the web methods because they are listed in the WSDL. The WSDL generation is fairly static - it is based on the [WebMethod] attributes on your methods. There is really no ability to remove items from the generated WSDL.

If you can switch to WCF, you will find this much, much, easier. In the meantime, you'll just have to use authorization - prevent some clients from calling some methods.

Comment: Thanks John, we are in process of moving to WCF but it will take some more time before this asmx sees it happening.